# Changing the amount of weeks displayed on CalendarView

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to develop a very basic timetabling app using Android Studios. When I drag on the calendar view it displays the whole month but I would only want the first two weeks, I've tried looking at editing the UI of the calendar but haven't been able to find anything so far.

I was wonder is this definitely possible or will I have to develop my own calendar?

Answer (score 0):

try inspirating with this example and use library in this project

[Project](https://github.com/SpongeBobSun/mCalendarView)

If you have some questions about this library, I work with this library and everything work good, but it's little tangled.